# How to change Solution Name display on authorize.net under Transaction Source useing Drupal commerce

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I am using Drupal commerce Authorize.Net module for transaction.

When I review Transaction Detail on https://sandbox.authorize.net/ site, it display **Solution Name:    Commerce Guys** under **Transaction Source**.

[image]

How can I change it with my custom one?

Answer (score 2):

It's unfortunate that Authorize.Net identifies it as "Commerce Guys". It should be identifying the request as coming from "Drupal Commerce", which allows them to monitor adoption by users of the module overall (and justifies their continued investment in our community). I'll follow-up with them immediately to change this so it's actually identifying the solution and not the creator of the solution instead (i.e. Commerce Guys). Changing what appears there is only possible from their end, but I have a contact who should be able to get it done.